# string search in app script is not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax, comparison-operators

I am having one google sheet (sheet1) of supplier details. The column names are  CODE, SUPP, PLACE with rows of around 300 plus.  When I want to search the supplier name having "IMPEX",  I am using following google sheet query formula:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C200, "SELECT A, B, C WHERE B CONTAINS '%IMPEX%' ",1)
```

the Google sheet query is fetching the details.  And the results comes as following, which  is fine.

```
CODE    SUPP                         PLACE
1138    IMPEX STEELS PVT LTD         BANGALORE
1278    SHIVAM IMPEX LTD             BANGALORE
1345    IMPEX INC,                   CHENNAI
1456    RADHE STEEL IMPEX            MUMBAI
```

Now I want to use this in Google Apps Script.  I wrote the following code but it is not working. Could someone edit or rectify it?

```
function searchName{

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");/
  var dr = ws.getRange("A1:C360"); 
  var data = dr.getValues(); 

  //show the search results in the same sheet on D15 cells
  Var D15 = ws.getRange("D15:F20")

  var result = [];

   for (var i =0; i< data.length; i++){
         if(data[i][1] = "IMPEX"){        
          result.push(data[i]);

         // Logger.log(result)
         d15.displayRow(result);
          
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(data[i][1] = "IMPEX")` probably it should be `if(data[i][1].includes("IMPEX"))`

Comment: `If` means a comparison, so you should use `==`

Comment: Thank you @YuriKhristich for your response. It is working fine in Logger.log.  But I want to display the results  from Row   {D15,E15,F15} and next row in {D16,E16,E16}...as per the Result data. Could you provide some code please?

Comment: Alas, I don't understand your goal. What do you mean 'I want to display'? Do you need to put the result in a table? It would be easier if you show your desired output (a table? I suppose).

Comment: What do you by it's doesn't work? How are you running the function? Is there an error message shown? P.S. Is not clear if the function has syntax errors or there was a transcription error.